# error showing malformed JSON in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, grails

I have this string that I'm passing into JS from a grails controller and I'm trying to run a $.parseJSON() method on the string in jquery and it fails. When I tested it in JSON lint its malformed but I can't figure out why.

```
  private String copydec = """   {
                   "header" : "",
                    "copy" : "<p style='font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;'><b>Title for some copy</b></p>
                    <p><span style='font-size: 12px;'>Lorem ipsum onsectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio.</span></p>
                    <p><span style='font-size: 12px;'>Lorem ipsum onsectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio.</span></p>
                    <p><span style='font-size: 12px;'></span></p>
                    <p style='font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;'></p>
    <p style="font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"></p>",
                    "checkboxLabel" : "<p>What can I help you with</p>
                    <p></p>"
    }               """
```

Tried adding it all on one line with no line breaks as was suggested in the comments but still getting malformed.

```
        {
           "header" : "","terms" : "<p style="font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><b>Recurring Payments Authorization</b></p><p><span style="font-size: 12px;">Lorem ipsum onsectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio.</span></p><p><span style="font-size: 12px;">Lorem ipsum onsectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio.</span></p><p><span style="font-size: 12px;"></span></p><p style="font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"></p><p style="font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"></p>","checkboxLabel" : "<p>I accept these terms and conditions.</p><p></p>","digitalSignatureDescription" : "Digital Signature","digitalSignatureDetails" : "Complete digital phone authorization description consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore Description consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore","acceptTermsDesc" : "You must accept these Terms and Conditions to continue with your order.","timestamp" : "07/30/2013 12:58:39","version" : "","signatureDateLabel" : "Date","fullNameLabel" : "Full Name","birthdateLabel" : "Date of Birth","digitalSignatureID" : "BILLING","signatureType" : "TANDC","signatureMethod" : "SIGNATURE"
        }
```

**UPDATE:** 
Based on dmahapatro answer where he got it to work in JS fiddle. I changed my code inside my grails controller to look like this.

```
private String copydec = """
'{"header":"","copy":"<p style=\'font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;\'><b>Title for some copy</b></p><p><span style=\'font-size: 12px;\'>Lorem ipsum onsectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio.</span></p><p><span style=\'font-size: 12px;\'>Lorem ipsum onsectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio.</span></p><p><span style=\'font-size: 12px;\'></span></p><p style=\'font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;\'></p><p style=\'font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;\'></p>","checkboxLabel" : "<p>What can I help you with</p><p></p>"}'
"""
```

In my index.gsp file I'm dumping out the controller variable into a hidden input field.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="copy" value='${bean.copydec}' />
```

Then accessing this from my JS file.

```
   var str = $('#termsAndConditions').val();
   console.log("str = ", str);
   var termsJSON = $.parseJSON( str );
```

Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: There are several errors, paste it at jsonlint.com

Comment: WHat's the code like? Where do you get the JSON from?

Comment: The code comes from a variable in a grails controller. private String copydec. IT's coming in as a string. But when I try to parse it to JSON in JS I get an error.

Comment: Also, you are using double quotes inside the json string properties. ` <p style="font-family` for example

Comment: Johan not sure what you mean I tried change all my quotes to single and got other errors. Can you give me an example from what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be formatted as one line like so...
Or at least with included line breaks in the text..

```
{
"header": "",
"copy": "Title for some copy Lorem ipsum onsectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio.Lorem ipsum onsectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio.",
"checkboxLabel": "What can I help you with"
 }
```

Comment: I have used html tags in JSON before without any issues. You just removed all the tags.

Comment: He's trying to tell you that you can't have actual LINE BREAKS in your JSON structure.

Comment: Ok got you but I tried putting all my JSON on one line and keeping the html tags and I still get malformed JSON.

Comment: Are you sure the quotes are being escaped properly?

Comment: When you say escaped? how would I make sure this.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnDAA/) it when `'` or `"` is escaped from the html content.

Based on OP's update to question:
The quotes has to be used wisely when framing a Json string. In this case:

```
//Make sure you remove the single quote if you use triple quotes for multiline
private String copydec = """
   Your Json String
"""
```

OR

```
//Assign the json string in one line
private String copydec = 'Your json String'
```

OR

```
//Use three single quotes for multiple
private String copydec = '''
   Your json String
'''
```

This wont work:

```
//Note the single quote after triple quotes which is the way you are using
private String copydec = """
   'Your json String'
"""
```

[This example](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5934910/) illustrates the same.

Comment: Ok great this works if I just add it as a variable to a JS file directly which is not something I can do. When I add it to my grails controller as a string and then dump it into a hidden input field I get this error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @Chapsterj Was the answer helpful in any way?